# Login page with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm setting up my security support in Spring and I am exploring what it has to offer. While setting up my login URL and view, I needed to register simple controllers for home and login URL. Concretely, code is:

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login");
    }
```

In line `registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");` it seems that that line simply adds controller for URL "/" and for GET to that URL simply uses view "home" for rendering.
Did I get it right? Main question is about line `registry.addViewController("/login");`. Here I add controller for "/login" URL.
But how application knows which view to use? When I tried the app it really used "login" view I created.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are on the right track but not completely. If you are NOT logged in and open the URL "yourdomain.tld/" you will be redirected to the URL "yourdomain.tld/home" which normally could be a login page. (first line). Of course, you need a controller to handle this request and return a proper JSP/JSF page.

Your second line is not needed. The trick is that with such a configuration you can use the URL "yourdoamin.tld/" with a different page for logged in users.

And to answer your main question, you need a controller for every URL or part of the URL you want to use. And within this controller, you can choose the views according to the requested URL.

Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/info")
@Scope(value="session")
public class InfoController extends AbstractWebController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView infoPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = this.getModelAndView("info/infopage");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

This controller is responsible for all URLs starting with "yourdomain.tld/info". And as you can see I have only the URL "yourdomain.tld/info" to return a proper view. In this example I return "infopage.jsp". You can add code to return different views for other pages.